# Is there any tool that provides paragraph level premissions to be set on a document?

Tags: permissions

I'm in need of a tool/software that provides paragraph level permissions to be set on a document? If you have any idea about this or a similar software please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no tool that provides this functionality till now.